# How load/get document in to the VisualForce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I've three documents as image in my document tab under the folder XYZ. Now I want to load one as Header, one as footer and one as body. How can I do that in Salesforce visualforce page ?

Assume I have three documents with me

1. Email Footer Support
2. Email Header Support
3. Health Service Logo

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Have you done any research on your own to try to address this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In order to include the Header, footer and background image to a VF Page , use the static resource to save the images. Store the header and footer images in a zip folder say XYZ.zip. And a separate static resource to store the background image say BackGroundImg. Please refer the below VF page :

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="HeaderFooterController">
    <style>

        body {
            margin:70px 80px 100px 100px;
        }
        div#fixedheader {
            position:fixed;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            width:100%;
            color:#CCC;
            //background:#333;
            padding:8px;
        }
        div#fixedfooter {
            position:fixed;
            bottom:0px;
            left:0px;
            width:100%;
            color:#CCC;
            //background:#333;
            padding:8px;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="fixedheader"><apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.HeaderFooter, 'XYZ/Header.png')}" width="100%" height="50" /></div>
    <body style="background-image:url('{!$Resource.BackGroundImg}');">
         <apex:form id="mnFrmId">
            <table id="TblId">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <apex:outputText > Email Address: </apex:outputText>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:inputText id="myEmlId" value="{!email}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:outputText rendered="{!shwErrorMail}"> <span style="color:red;">{!emailError}</span></apex:outputText>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                    

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <apex:commandButton value="Click me!"  action="{!checkEmail}" reRender="mnFrmId"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

        </apex:form>
    </body>
    <div id="fixedfooter"><apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.HeaderFooter, 'XYZ/Footer.png')}" width="100%" height="50" /></div>
</apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public with sharing class HeaderFooterController {
public String emailError{get;set;}
    public String email{get;set;}
    public String passwordError{get;set;}
    public String password{get;set;}
    public Boolean shwErrorMail{get;set;}
    public Boolean shwErrorPswd{get;set;}

    public HeaderFooterController(){
        shwErrorMail = False; 
        shwErrorPswd = False;   
    }

    public PageReference checkEmail() {
        shwErrorMail = False; 
        shwErrorPswd = False;
        if(email == ''){
            emailError ='Please Enter The Email Address';
            shwErrorMail = True;
        }

        if(password == ''){
            passwordError = 'Please Enter The Password';
            shwErrorPswd = True;
        }        

        return null;
    }


}
```

Here the main content of the page must be kept within the   tags which will help to show the background image . Here div with id "fixedheader" will show the header image. And div with id "fixedfooter" will help to show the footer image.

Comment: is there any way we can load documents? I have those image present as document. Any pointers + code ?. Also could you please attached screen shot for your above code. I would be glad to see how it looks ?